# "A network-related or instance-specific error" occurs intermittently

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know there are a lot of questions in SO and google answering this issue. But, my application has a login page and a search page which gives search results. AFter the results are displayed, the users can click on a button to process the records.

Processing the records updates a db field..nothing more than that.

Users are able to login to the application, search and even able to process the records. But, sometime in the day(or may be later in the day)...they are not able to process the records...the server's application log shows this error of 'A network-related....".

I'm of the opinion that as more users start using the application, the sql server connection is not being  made due to load. But, I'm entirely not sure about it.

Can someone help?

Comment: can you share how you connect to the database in your connection string? Is it localhost or across a network? Is it in the same subnet?

Comment: The Database is in a different server but on the same VM. The login and search process are able to connect to the same database using the same connections string. Even the Process activity happens, but not always. <add name="DMSCON" connectionString="Data Source=Insance\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=sa;Password=password@123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: check the eventlogs for any kind of sql server restarts or shutdowns, etc...I guess you should see it in the Application eventlog.

Comment: Initially I would have assumed so. But, a check of the event log did not reveal any such abrupt restarts.

Comment: Does the application generate an actual error? More than 'A network related...' would be useful.

Comment: Are you referring to the stack trace?

Comment: does the error happen when the end users are accessing a specific page in your application, or, is the problem generally occurring in any page that has a db call? Are people getting the YSOD?